# Allure Results Empty when test is triggered via Maven

Tags: java, selenium, maven, testng, allure

I have configured Allure in my POM xml to generate the test report and when I trigger the tests via maven the allure results xml is empty. However when the same test is triggered from Intellij the results are proper. Could someone help me out here on what is going wrong. This was working until the last day and all of a sudden without any changes on POM this is behaving this way. Here s the POM xml code

```
`<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>fgrest</groupId>
  <artifactId>fgrest</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>
                        -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                    </argLine>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
                <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
                <version>2.10.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <resultsDirectory>${project.basedir}/target/allure-results</resultsDirectory>
                    <reportingOutputDirectory>${project.basedir}/target/allure-reports</reportingOutputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
                <artifactId>allure-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>xxxx</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
      <aspectj.version>1.8.10</aspectj.version>
      <allure.results.directory>${project.basedir}/target/allure-results</allure.results.directory>
      <allure.report.directory>${project.basedir}/target/allure-report</allure.report.directory>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.14.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20180813</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.5</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.8</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
          <artifactId>allure-testng</artifactId>
          <version>2.10.0</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
          <artifactId>allure-testng-adaptor</artifactId>
          <version>1.5.4</version>
          <exclusions>
              <exclusion>
                  <groupId>junit</groupId>
                  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
              </exclusion>
          </exclusions>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>3.14.0</version>
        </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
          <artifactId>allure-java-adaptor-api</artifactId>
          <version>1.5.4</version>
          <scope>compile</scope>
      </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Tests are running and only the Allure report generation has issues. Anyway after lot of googling I have managed to solve this issue. I have added the aspect jweaver dependency out of the Plugin tags as well under the dependencies section and updated the surefire plugin to 3.0.0-M1 version and now Allure results xml are populated with data.